# how to use multiple and or operator with like in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i use the following statement but it does not working properly.

```
$query = "select * from employee where status ='Active' and employee_id! ='".$data['employee_id']."') and (first_name like '$data%' or last_name like '$data%' or batch like '$data%' or job_title like '$data%' or company like '$data%' ORDER BY first_name";
      $result = mysql_query($query);
```

Like i need to fetch all result but not employee_id=5;
but i get the employee_id=5 result;is there any issue in query and other simplest way to use this query

Comment: your query syntax seems to be incorrect, there are 2 `)`, but only `(`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code $data['employee_id']  and like '$data%  use both same variable 
you need to change $data for search value. it is overwrite.

do this and check

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space after `!` mark

Like this

```
where status ='Active' and employee_id !='".$data['employee_id']."')
```

Check this link to learn about operator http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Note:mysql is depricated learn Mysqli_ function or PDO or both

for Mysqli_ fucntion check this link http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php
For PDO Check this link http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
$query = "select * from employee where status ='Active' and employee_id !='".$data['employee_id']."' and (first_name like '$data%' or last_name like '$data%' or batch like '$data%' or job_title like '$data%' or company like '$data%') ORDER BY first_name";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```